# Progress bar updates from parallel tasks are delayed compared to task completion

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working with a progress bar in a C#/.NET application using Windows Forms that is updated from parallel running tasks. Each task invokes a change of the value by 1 on the progress bar exactly as many times as there are steps in the progress bar. However, even though the tasks are always finished promptly, there's a delay of approximately 0.5 to 1 second before the progress bar is completed.

**Form File**

```cs
var progress = new Progress<int>();
progress.ProgressChanged += (_, value) =>
{
    progressBarUploading.Value = value;
};
```

**Other File**

```cs
internal async Task UploadProject(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    List<Task> listOne = new();

    foreach (var item in Project.items)
    {
        //do some stuff

        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        progress.Report(counter);

        listOne.Add(Task.Run(() => UploadItems(item, progress)));
    }
    // Waits until all the Tasks are finished 
    await Task.WhenAll(listOne);
    progress.Report(Project.itemCountTotal);
}

internal async Task UploadItems(AzureDevOpsPOSTitem item, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    List<Task> listTwo = new();

    foreach (var newItem in item.list)
    {
        // do some other stuff

        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        progress.Report(counter);

        listTwo.Add(Task.Run(() => UploadItems(newItem, progress)));
    }
    // Waits until all the Tasks are finished.
    await Task.WhenAll(listTwo);
}
```

I suspect that this delay might be due to the UI thread handling the progress updates while the tasks complete on separate threads. Is there a way to ensure that the progress bar updates in sync with the completion of the tasks, without this delay?

Additionally, I've attempted to set the progress bar to 100% after all tasks are completed using `progress.Report(maxLength);`, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The progress bar continues to increment step by step (presumably due to the `progress.Report` calls from the completed tasks). Is there a way to set the progress bar immediately to 100% after all tasks have been completed and stop the unexecuted `progress.Reports`?

Comment: Application.DoEvents() after report maybe help

Comment: don't really understand your "progress" routine, because you are incrementing the counter and reporting this counter without actually waiting for anything. So the counter could be already 1000, while this line `await Task.WhenAll(listOne);` still is executing. - so your counter only indicates the tasks initialized and not the tasks completed.

Comment: See this sample to understand what I mean: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cm4APM - compard to this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LW8w5h

Answer (score 0):

You are probably drowning the progress bar with update requests, and the progress bar has an internal delay during which it animates the bar towards the new value. Send fewer updates, especially if they're trivial (and thus finish very fast).

And this is even more true because you're reporting the progress without awaiting the completion of individual tasks, you should only report the progress *after* they're finished, like this:

```
async Task UploadItemsHelper()
{
    await Task.Run(() => UploadItems(item, progress));
    
    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    progress.Report(counter);
}
listOne.Add(UploadItemsHelper());
```

Though you seem to be getting confused about threads with your code -- you don't need that interlocked increment since that seems to be running on the GUI thread in the first place. That's another big problem with your code, everything keeps getting serialized back to the GUI thread.

Comment: Also, uploading items sounds like an I/O bound operation, not a CPU bound one, so you shouldn't run `Task.Run` on it, you should have it be async in the first place.